# WCF Single Service Implementation - Multiple Behaviours, Funny WSDL

Tags: wcf, binding, wsdl

I have a simple IIS hosted service that I need to expose both through a wsHttpBinding endpoint without throttling and a basicHttpBinding endpoint with throttling.

I configure my services as follows:

```
<service name="Calculator">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/WCFTwoEndpoints/Calculate.svc"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="Calculator"
      contract="WCFTwoEndpoints.ICalculate" />
  </service>
  <service name="ThrottledCalculator" behaviorConfiguration ="Throttled">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/WCFTwoEndpoints/ThrottledCalculate.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="ThrottledCalculator"
      contract="WCFTwoEndpoints.ICalculate" />
  </service>
```

This gives me two service endpoints, I can browse to each .svc individually and pull up the WSDL. Problem is, in each case the WSDL describes the service as using basicHttp binding, I would have expected wsHttp binding for the Calculate.svc.

I've pasted a section of the WSDL below:

```
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculate" type="tns:ICalculate">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Addition">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ICalculate/Addition" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Calculate">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculate" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ICalculate">
<soap:address location="http://rb-t510/WCFTwoEndpoints/ThrottledCalculate.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I think I've missed something obvious here but I can't spot it. Any ideas?

Many thanks

Rob.